# Electrostatics, System of Charges

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electrostatics, electric-fields, potential-energy

At $t=0$, a positive point charge of mass $m$ is projected toward another positive point charge  of mass $m$ in free space. At the instant of minimum separation kinetic energy of the system of two charges becomes $1/n$  times of initial kinetic energy of the system. Find $n$?
I have tried solving this and know the key concepts but i do not get the answer!

Comment: In the future please demonstrate that you have made considerable effort to solve any homework-like problem, and indicate what specifically you do not understand.  Otherwise your question will likely be flagged and put on hold.

Comment: Hi Ayush and welcome to the Physics SE! Please note that this is not a homework help site. Please see [this Meta post on asking homework questions](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/714/how-do-i-ask-homework-questions-on-physics-stack-exchange) and [this Meta post for "check my work" problems](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/6093/should-any-check-my-work-questions-be-made-on-topic).

Answer (score 1):

This is a homework-like question, so I will not provide a full answer.  Here are a couple of good things to think about on your way to the answer:

What is special about the velocities (or momenta or kinetic energies) of the particles at the instant of minimum separation?

What quantities are conserved throughout the interaction?

Comment: well, i know relative velocity becomes zero at minimum separation, forces are balanced
and this can be solved by energy conservation, the thing is how? and it's not a homework question, i am in 7th grade

Comment: Whoa, you edited... Okay, it is technically possible to solve this while utilizing energy conservation, but **much** simpler if you consider momentum conservation.  (The issue with energy is that some of the energy is stored in the electric field, which complicates things.  All of the momentum is in the mass of charges at all times.)  You are correct that relative velocity is zero.  Since they have the same mass, this means that momentum is divided equally between them.

Comment: so is this correct 
$mv=2mv'$ ,$v'=v/2$
 Initial kinetic energy = $mv^2/2$ Final kinetic energy=$mv^2/8  + mv^2/8$ = $mv^2/4$ Hence n is 2.

Comment: Yes.  Note that we used no information of any kind other than the fact that there were two objects of equal mass, one of which was initially at rest.  This result applies to ANY such two particle interaction, whether it be two bouncy balls colliding, or two blobs of clay sticking to each other.